# How to calculate the Funding Benefit of Equity for a profitability or FTP calculator for a credit union

Tags: ftp

I am creating a RAROC/FTP model for different loan types on a credit union balance sheet.
I am stuck on how to calculate the funding benefit of equity that would be netted out of my cost of funds benchmark. An example below shows the funding benefit @ 0.17%.  Does anyone know where that may be sourced from or what calc method is being used to arrive at that result?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially calculating the Weighted Average Cost of Capital.

Target Capital Ratio * Risk Weight * Cost of Funds = Funding Benefit of equity %

Ex:
Risk weight = 75%
Capital Ratio = 10%
Cost of Funds = 5%

Funding Benefit of Equity = 38bps